# How can we calculate distance of Light?

Tags: distance

Say I am using torch , and I want to calculate distance of light it travelled if I put it upwards , how can I calculate the distance of light ?

Comment: The distance it travels before what? Before it strikes some other object? Then you just need to know how far away that other object is.

Comment: Light has a fixed speed. Figuring how far it travels just requires that you masure the time after you turned on the light source. And then multiply that time with the speed of light.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE :-) Do you mean how far the torchlight travels until it fades out? i.e. how far away the torch is able to illuminate things?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_free_path#Optics

Answer (score 1):

Light always travels with the speed C = 3.0e8 m/s. Just check the time when torch was switched on and current time and that will give you distance travelled (if there is any obstacle the direction may change)